# Start php.exe invisible with C#?

Tags: c#, php, cmd, window, invisible

I want to start a php script with my local php.exe and don't want to see the cmd-window that appears when I do so.

This is my code:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"php.exe", "script.php");
```

What argument can I use to make the php.exe invisible?
I read something about a "php-win.exe" but I have to do it with the normal php.exe and already tried some other methods (like hide.exe) but none of them would work.

Comment: you making a keygen?

Comment: No, i am not making a keygen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass a [Process start info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo(v=vs.110)) to `Process.Start` instead.

```
var info = new ProcessStartInfo(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"php.exe", "script.php") 
{
  // check the various properties to define your process. For example:
  WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
  CreateNoWindow = true 
};

Process.Start(info);
```

Comment: unfortunately this doesnt work, still get a window :(

Comment: @LennB Check my edit. If it does not work, open up the documentation and have a look at all the parameters. Try some. I don't have a php.exe, I cannot know what it does or how it looks.